# Loss of polymorphism after pattern matching

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, pattern-matching

The following code is intended to produce either a Double or an Integer. `s` is assumed to be either `negate` or `id`; `n` the whole part; and `f` the fractional part or `Nothing` for an integer.

```
computeValue :: Num a => (a->a) -> Integer -> (Maybe Double) -> Either Double Integer
computeValue s n Nothing = Right $ s n
computeValue s n (Just a) = Left $ s (fromIntegral n + a)
```

when I compile this I get:

```
test1.hs:2:28:
    Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Double'
    Expected type: Either Double Integer
      Actual type: Either Double a
    In the expression: Right $ s n
    In an equation for `computeValue':
        computeValue s n Nothing = Right $ s n

test1.hs:2:38:
    Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Double'
    In the first argument of `s', namely `n'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `s n'
    In the expression: Right $ s n
```

It seems like somehow the compiler has lost track of the fact that `s` is polymorphic.  What happened here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`s` is not polymorphic from inside of your function: you can use any function that works on *some* `Num` instance as this parameter, it might be a function that only works on `Complex`! What you need is an universally quantified function `s`, i.e. one that can actually be called with *any* `Num` instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

computeValue :: (forall a . Num a => a->a) -> Integer -> Maybe Double -> Either Double Integer
computeValue s n Nothing = Right $ s n
computeValue s n (Just a) = Left $ s (fromIntegral n + a)
```

That works then:

```
Prelude Data.Either> computeValue id 3 Nothing
Right 3
Prelude Data.Either> computeValue negate 57 (Just pi)
Left (-60.1415926535898)
```

Comment: Interesting!  I had found what was wrong (it really wanted an `Either a a`) as a return, but I didn't realize there was a way around it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: You actually need _universally_ quantified `s` and that's what the rank 2 signature does. `ExistentialQuantification` does nothing in this example, the important extension is `Rank2Types` only.

Comment: @Vitus: ah, right! I keep mixing it up, but that makes much more sense, thinking about it. Edited.